# How do I truly reset every setting and remove all project in tfs (in the web portal)

Tags: tfs, source-control-explorer

I am trying to reset every single setting inside TFS and **Remove all project and Work Items**..
is there any way to reset every single setting to the factory default?

Comment: Please clarify question: what do you want to keep? which TFS version you have? Why source control tag?

Comment: I use the web portal TFS, And I want to Delete everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting a team project permanently removes data associated with that project from the database. You cannot recover it later.

1. Open the administration context for the team project collection by choosing the  gear icon.
2. Open the .... menu for the team project that you want to delete.
3. You must type the name of the team project in order to initiate the delete operation.

[image]

Check: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/delete-team-project